# Density plot with a list of $ (x, y) $ data

Tags: data, visualization

I have a list of $ (x, y) $, say `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ..., {x1000, y1000}}` and would like to make a density plot.

I understand that I may categorize the data into different groups first, and count the number of element in each group, then make a `ListDensityPlot`.

I would like to ask if there is other faster way to do it, or any built-in function can be used?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a histogram rather than density plot. Histogram3D should plot your list as it is (without having to gather it into counts)

Comment: Try SmoothDensityHistogram.

Comment: How about showing some sample data and the desired plotting?

Answer (score 2):

```
Histogram3D[Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2}], {1000}]]
```

[image]

which takes $0.078$ seconds.